# Does this C++ class containing a variable size array use dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management

Does doing something like this use dynamic memory allocation?

```
template <class T, int _size> 
class CArray 
{ 
public:
    ... 
private:
    T m_data[_size]; 
};
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on behind the scenes when I create the object?

```
CArray<SomeObject, 32> myStupidArray;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, templates are evaluated at compile time. If you're interested you can have g++ spit out the class hierarchy where you can verify its size:

```
template <class T, int _size>
class CArray
{
public:
private:
  T m_data[_size];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  CArray<int, 32> myStupidArray1;
  CArray<int, 8> myStupidArray2;
  CArray<int, 64> myStupidArray3;
  CArray<int, 1000> myStupidArray4;
}
```

Compile with `-fdump-class-hierarchy`:

```
g++ -fdump-class-hierarchy blah.cc
```

There should be a file named `blah.cc.t01.class` in the current directory:

```
Class CArray<int, 32>
   size=128 align=4
   base size=128 base align=4
CArray<int, 32> (0x40be0d80) 0

Class CArray<int, 8>
   size=32 align=4
   base size=32 base align=4
CArray<int, 8> (0x40be0e80) 0

Class CArray<int, 64>
   size=256 align=4
   base size=256 base align=4
CArray<int, 64> (0x40be0f80) 0

Class CArray<int, 1000>
   size=4000 align=4
   base size=4000 base align=4
CArray<int, 1000> (0x40be6000) 0
```

Answer (score 11):

No, it will be allocated in-place (e.g. either on the stack, or as part of a containing object).

With templates the parameters are evaluated at compile-time so your code effectively becomes;

```
class CArray 
{ 
public:
    ... 
private:
    SomeObject m_data[32]; 
};
```

Comment: It's important to note that CArray<SomeObject,32> is essentially the object type as well. In other words CArray<SomeObject,33> and CArray<SomeObject,34> are completely unrelated types. This usually doesn't matter than much, but it can.

Answer (score 3):

[Templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates.html) are evaluated at compile time, so m_data[_size] is compiled as m_data[32].

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not use dynamic memory allocation. The compiler knows how much memory needs to be allocated, it is decided at compile-time, not at run-time.

It does not make any sense to explain C++ templates here, they are explained pretty well at other pages, like in the [C++ faq lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.1).

Answer (score 0):

The size of the array is known at compile time, so no, it won't be using dynamic memory allocation here.  If you declare the array in a function scope then it'll be put on the stack just like any other type of object.

When you define variable-sized objects like this, what's really happening is that the compiler is building a class definition 'to order'.  You'll just be using a class definition that contains 'T m_data[32]' in it.

Answer (score 0):

1- Templates are evaluated only at compile time. So this array will be of size 32

2- You can't create an array on the stack using a variable, it must be a constant that can be evaluated at compile time, else you can use new (or malloc)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic memory allocation typically occurs when you call the `new` operator (or one of its friends). This allocates a chunk of memory from a memory reserve commonly referred to as a heap. Remember that unlike static allocation, the compiler doesn't take care of free-ing the memory and so you have to do it manually using the `delete` operator (or a suitable version thereof).